I'm getting error while running a C file from gcc in vscode
Hey there I'm a newbie to C right now and just started learning two days ago, I installed VScode editor for C language and also Installed MinGW compiler for C and set its path in environment variables.
But when I run the program in the terminal by writing
It shows this error...
        PS G:\Skills\CODES AND NOTES\C> gcc first.c -o first.exe
    gcc.exe: error: first.c: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.

I don't know what is causing this please help me in this matter
I tried opening the folder in PowerShell and ran the file.exe generated and there it printed the string I wrote in the program...
        PS G:\Skills\CODES AND NOTES\C\CHAPTER 1> ./first.exe
    Yo, Exams are nearby and I'm here with Harry Learning C.


Please don't post images of text. [Edit] your question to copy-paste all text as text.

And if you read the error message, it should be pretty easy to figure out. When you build, are you in the exact same directory as the source file?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the About page soon and also visit the links describing How to Ask a Question and How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example. Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Just copy/paste your code into the question with \``cabove the first line and```` on the line after your code so it formats in fixed width with C syntax highlight. (that's 3 back-ticks  -- generally under the ESC key on keyboard) That will help everyone here help you.

The gcc.exe: error: first.c: No such file or directory should be screaming loudly at you that the fie gcc is trying to find isn't there (or is in another directory). Much easier to compile from the command line and work your way into vscode. It is an ass-kicking IDE, one of my favorite, but it has a fairly steep learning curve with the .json config files, etc.... You don't need the nicieties it provides yet, but it does make programming easier. Once you have learned to compile from the command line, then you can tell vscode how you want it to compile your code.

The successful run is executed from G:\Skills\CODE AND NOTES\C\CHAPTER 1, while the failed compilation attempt occurs from G:\Skills\CODE AND NOTES\C. Assuming you didn't explicitly specify another path while compiling first.c, you should run gcc from G:\Skills\CODE AND NOTES\C\CHAPTER 1 too.

how do I run from G:\Skills\CODE AND NOTES\C\CHAPTER 1 ??

@ShreyashOjha cd G:\Skills\CODE AND NOTES\C\CHAPTER 1, and then run the command.

I tried doing the same in terminal but it showed this error
`Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be
found that accepts argument 'AND'.
At line:1 char:1

cd G:\Skills\CODES AND NOTES\C\CHAPTER 1

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:)   
 [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId: PositionalParameterNo  
 tFound, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand `



@ShreyashOjha you have spaces in your path. You must enclose it in quotes. Otherwise the shell treats it as multiple files. That is not a C Issue but fundamental computer behaviour.
